# i want hide some character from email like Sha***aj@gmail.com

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed a application, it is user based application. int this app if user forget his password, then user can reset his password only through his email id and in case if user is not remember his email id which is associated with his account at that time i want retrieve password in a social security numbers like sha***aj@gmail.com. How can i achieve this please help me with this problem that will be appreciated. Thank you.

i have got this code from stak over flow but it is not meet my requirement. It is good for only phone number not for email

```
public static string GetMaskedEmail(string number)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(number))
        return string.Empty;

    if (number.Length <= 12)
        return number;

    string last12 = number.Substring(number.Length - 12, 12);
    var maskedChars = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < number.Length - 12; i++)
    {
        maskedChars.Append(number[i] == '-' ? "-" : "#");
    }
    return maskedChars + last12;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Work is a little slow tonight, so I fired up Xamarin Studio and whipped this up for you. This shouldn't be taken as an example in best coding practices, really not at all.

Though what this will provide is a functioning example, from which you can take and build into your own method and hopefully learn in the process. A great resource for reference, if you get lost at all while reading over any code, is MSDN which if you haven't visited yet I would suggest doing so and bookmarking for future use.

```
using System;

namespace EmailHash
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length <= 0) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("No values were passed to application.");
                return;
            }
            string email = args[0];

            int indexOfAt = email.IndexOf ("@");
            if (indexOfAt == -1) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to find '@' symbol within email.");
                return;
            }

            int indexStart = 3;
            int indexEnd = indexOfAt - 2;
            if (indexStart >= indexEnd)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not enough characters in email to mask value.");
                return;
            }

            string hashedEmail = email.Replace(email.Substring(indexStart, indexEnd - indexStart), "***");

            Console.WriteLine("Original email: " + email);
            Console.WriteLine("Hashed email: " + hashedEmail);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```